# What is wrong with my reply here

Tags: discussion, answers

[This question about the sun's circumference](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/68120/how-is-suns-equatorial-circumference-measured/68125#68125), I answered with what I *thought* was a helpful answer - it seems that a couple of others found it useful (2 upvotes), but I am getting grief about the answer being "while strictly correct, but is enormously unsatisfying".

Why not then, if an answer is "enormously unsatisfying", post n alternative answer?

What have I done wrong this time?

Comment: You haven't done anything wrong, and no one has claimed that you have.

Comment: like I said, I just got rid of that answer, I now know to be extremely careful when/if replying in future

Comment: Again, you've done nothing wrong. It could have been phrased in a clearer manner but basically the commenters were asking for a clarification. The answer was correct.

Comment: Hi Damien, I think you should not get scared that easily by a stingy commenter ;-). I agree with the people who say that you did nothing wrong and as two people obviously liked your answer, you could consider undeleting it...

Comment: I am not 'scared', confused more to the point

Comment: @DamienIgoe: Happens all the time. Over here it looks like dmckee was clarifying Alan's comment by emphasizing his point/making it more stark. Easy to get confused by such comments.

Comment: If you feel like you're being attacked, just flag the comment and move on (or ping a mod in chat). This case was special, I agree, because it involved a mod -- but a flag still would have worked :) (no harm in going to meta though)

Comment: Okay, no worries, apologies for this mayhem... i'll indeed use the flag system.

Comment: *"This case was special, I agree, because it involved a mod"* For what it is worth, I asked for oversight on the moderation chat. It really is important that somebody watches the watchmen and I try to encourage this.

Answer (score 7):

Nobody downvoted your answer. That indicates that nobody thought it was unhelpful; on the other hand, two people thought it *was* helpful. So honestly, your complaint is without merit. If people actually think something is wrong with your answer, they'll downvote it.

Also note that posting an unsatisfying (or unhelpful, wrong, etc.) answer is not technically *wrong*, in the sense that it's not against the rules here. So you haven't *done* anything wrong.

By the way, keep in mind that if e.g. I find another person's answer unsatisfying, inadqeuate, wrong, or so on, that has no bearing on whether I should post my own answer. The argument "don't criticize me if you can't do better" holds no water on this site.

Comment: I was not trying to use that argument, I was trying to determine how I stuffed up (again)

Comment: Sure, but asking why other people didn't post alternative answers doesn't help you with that.

Answer (score 6):

I confess to being one of those people.  I agree completely that you didn't need to delete your answer.  The pinhole camera suggestion meaningfully added to the discussion.  Reason is that you can't just take a protractor and measure the angle subtended by the sun.

Now the criticism was that we don't have a measurement of the distance to the sun.  I hope that you don't take this to mean that *you didn't contribute* to answering the question, because you did.

At the root of the quibbling, however, was the fact that someone asked a fairly low level question that has an extremely difficult answer.  Why do you think no one else has added an answer after that discussion?  Probably several people looked into it and quickly realized the problem is more difficult than they thought.

Using references on Earth, how do you establish an astronomical length scale?  That question is **insanely** hard.  But is that what was asked?  To be nit-picky, yes, it was.  It was a simple question that stumbled on a really advanced and difficult question.  To answer that advanced question, one would still start out where you started out.

Comment: I will try and fix my answer when i get home from work

Answer (score 5):

I can only repeat what I wrote before.

1. Your answer is strictly correct.
2. But you have assumed the hard part of the historical problem has already been solved and answered with a basic geometric identity so I found your answer to be uninteresting.

and emphasize that

- I did not vote your answer down.
- No one else had voted your answer down.
- A couple of people had found it useful enough to vote up.

Finally, I'm having a hard time understanding how you get from a +2/-0 result on an answer to understanding that you have "done [] something wrong" or "stuffed up". You are ahead with that answer and there is no reason to expect that you will ever be behind---the answer is correct as far as it goes.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the unsatisfying bit is the inclusion of "Distance from Earth to the Sun" in the formula.

I agree that the question is a bit unclear in this aspect; I think it's trying to ask "how was the Sun's diameter *first* measured". From this point of view, talking about the E-S distance just raises another question "how was the E-S distance calculated?"

To make a rough analogy<sup>1</sup>, this is similar to being asked "How can I calculate the circumference of the Earth", and answering "Multiply the diameter by $\pi$". Again, this is strictly correct, but not really satisfying.

<sup>1. I've tried to make the issue clearer in this analogy by exaggerating the situation. I've found that folks sometimes easily get offended by such exaggerated analogies, so I'm just mentioning that I don't mean to offend here :)</sup>

Comment: the post is fixed

Answer (score -1):

> What have I done wrong this time?

Initially being too sensitive to fair, constructive criticisim of your answer, that replaced one measurement with another, without explaining how the new measurement was to be carried out.

What did you do right?

Taking on board the criticism in the comments and improving the answer.

Comment: stating something is "enormously unsatisfying" is not constructive. The question ONLY stated the circumference of the sun (hence why I answered as such).
This issue is resolved, the answer is improved and I am just reviewing and editing as necessary (not replying though).

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with calling for a review by a larger amount of people of one's own disputed posts on meta or on chat. So Damien has done nothing wrong and this answer is not helpful to give him more selfconfidence ...